# Hadoop Mapper to read key-value pairs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is there a builtin InputFormat that I can use in a mapper function to read input lines of following format:

```
Name [key1#val1,key2#val2,key3#val3,key4#val4]
```

Sample input data may look like below:

```
sanjose [population#123,area#123,address#1,jkui,ty,tz#PST]
delhi [population#1823,area#1023,address#1,jkui,ty,tz#IST]
boston [population#1823,area#1023,address#1,jkui,ty,tz#EST]
```

Comment: How is the reducer supposed to work in your case? reducer can work on only a key, value pair unlike your format

Answer (score 0):

Set the property `mapreduce.input.keyvaluelinerecordreader.key.value.separator` and use `job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);`

In your case I believe `\t` is the Key Value delimiter